# Как передать onChange в пользовательский (materialize) компонент react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, textarea, materialize-css

Доброго времени суток!

Использую [react-materialize](http://react-materialize.github.io/), как передать onChange в компонент Textarea библиотеки materialize?

```
export const CreatePage = () => {

  const [text, setText] = useState("")

  return (
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col s8 offset-s2">
                <Textarea 
                    id="create-text"
                    type="text" 
                    value={text} 
                    onChange={e => setText(e.target.value)} 
                    s={12}
                    label="Введите текст"
                />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Выдаёт такой варнинг и ввод текста перестаёт работать:

[image: Предупреждение в консоли]

Также пробовал ставить вместо value -> defaultValue как написано. Тогда всё работает, но в базу ничего не записывается.

Но если убрать пользовательский компонент, написать вместо него textarea - всё работает и записывается в базу, но без красивостей компонента materialize.

Comment: Когда вы задаете `defaultValue` вместо `value`, должно всё нормально работать. Что значит *в базу ничего не записывается*?

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, имел ввиду "базу данных", конкретно в mongodb

Comment: Может я чего-то не понял, но при чем тут `Textarea`? Поясните пожалуйста, где в приведенном вами коде находится связь с БД? Что-то я впритык не вижу.

Comment: @Denis Bubnov, через useState и импорты. Я сильно порезал файл, чтобы не отвлекать от сути проблемы, т.к. знал что ошибка именно тут. И действительно она была здесь. Сейчас в ответе напишу даже несколько решений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Спасибо @Denis Bubnov, что не остался равнодушным. Так же спасибо
>   Павлу из телеграмма) Ощущаю себя как на поле чудес, а ведь это
>   прочитает только @Denis Bubnov. Ну да ладно

Нашёл даже несколько вариантов:

1) Добавить onChange в рендер прямо в библиотеку materialize в файл Textarea.js, как на изображении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2 - правильный) Обернуть в handleChange вызов onChange

```js
export const CreatePage = () => {

  const [text, setText] = useState("")

  const handleChange = e => setText(e.target.value)

  return (
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col s8 offset-s2">
                <Textarea 
                    id="create-text"
                    type="text" 
                    value={text} 
                    onChange={handleChange} 
                    s={12}
                    label="Введите текст"
                />
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Ахах, да, я прочитал, поставил +. Надеюсь ответ будет полезным.